# How do you add a transformer layer to a neural net?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I have an `Siamese-LSTM` implementation where the net itself is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
x = Sequential()
x.add(Embedding(len(embeddings), embedding_dim,
                weights=[embeddings], input_shape=(max_seq_length,), trainable=False))

x.add(LSTM(n_hidden))

shared_model = x
```

I want to be able compare it to the transformer equivalent. To be able to achieve that I need to replace `"LSTM"` with a transformer layer. Is there a way to make it work?

EDIT: LSTM comes from:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM
```